# Publish an aar file to Maven Central with Gradle not working

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

### **Publish an aar file to Maven Central with Gradle still not working:**

Ok, let's repeat all the steps I followed to manage to "Publish an aar file to Maven Central with Gradle" (I mainly followed this [guide](https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/Android-Update-Checker)), just to be sure...

1) I use "Android Studio" and I have this simple android lib that I would like to be available on maven: https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/Android-Update-Checker

2) In the UpdateCheckerLib folder I have the lib code abovementioned. And applying in the build.gradle of this folder `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` i got as output an .aar in the build/outputs/aar/ directory of the module's directory

3) My first step was to find an approved repository. I decided to use the [Sonatype OSS Repository](https://bintray.com/profile/edit). Here I registered a project opening a new Issue (Create --> Create Issue --> Community Support - Open Source Project Repository Hosting --> New Project) with groupid com.github.danielemaddaluno

4) So I added in the root of my project a file: `maven_push.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def sonatypeRepositoryUrl
if (isReleaseBuild()) {
    println 'RELEASE BUILD'
    sonatypeRepositoryUrl = hasProperty('RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL') ? RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL
            : "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
} else {
    println 'DEBUG BUILD'
    sonatypeRepositoryUrl = hasProperty('SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL') ? SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL
            : "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
}

def getRepositoryUsername() {
    return hasProperty('nexusUsername') ? nexusUsername : ""
}

def getRepositoryPassword() {
    return hasProperty('nexusPassword') ? nexusPassword : ""
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

                pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID

                repository(url: sonatypeRepositoryUrl) {
                    authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
                }

                pom.project {
                    name POM_NAME
                    packaging POM_PACKAGING
                    description POM_DESCRIPTION
                    url POM_URL

                    scm {
                        url POM_SCM_URL
                        connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
                        developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
                    }

                    licenses {
                        license {
                            name POM_LICENCE_NAME
                            url POM_LICENCE_URL
                            distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
                        }
                    }

                    developers {
                        developer {
                            id POM_DEVELOPER_ID
                            name POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    signing {
        required { isReleaseBuild() && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
        sign configurations.archives
    }

    task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
    }

    task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        //basename = artifact_id
        from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
    }

    task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        //basename = artifact_id
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
    }

    artifacts {
        //archives packageReleaseJar
        archives androidSourcesJar
        archives androidJavadocsJar
    }
}
```

6) I added in the file gradle.properties located in the root the following lines:

```
VERSION_NAME=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
VERSION_CODE=2
GROUP=com.github.danielemaddaluno

POM_DESCRIPTION=Android Update Checker
POM_URL=https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/Android-Update-Checker
POM_SCM_URL=https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/Android-Update-Checker
POM_SCM_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:danielemaddaluno/Android-Update-Checker.git
POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:danielemaddaluno/Android-Update-Checker.git
POM_LICENCE_NAME=The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
POM_LICENCE_URL=http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
POM_LICENCE_DIST=repo
POM_DEVELOPER_ID=danielemaddaluno
POM_DEVELOPER_NAME=Daniele Maddaluno
```

7) Inside the root I modified the build.gradle from this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

To this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

def isReleaseBuild() {
    return version.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
}

allprojects {
    version = VERSION_NAME
    group = GROUP

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-reporting'
```

8) I read that for each module or application I want to upload to central, I should:

- provide a gradle.propeties
- modify build.gradle to add the following line at the end:
  `apply from: '../maven_push.gradle'`

So in the UpdateCheckerLib folder I:

- Added a gradle.properties:

  ```
  POM_NAME=Android Update Checker
  POM_ARTIFACT_ID=androidupdatechecker
  POM_PACKAGING=aar
  ```
- Modified the build.gradle adding at the bottom of the file the following line: `apply from: '../maven_push.gradle'`

9) In order to sign my artifacts I did:

```
gpg --gen-key
gpg --list-keys  --> get my PubKeyId...
gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-keys PubKeyId
```

10) I added a file to `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` path with a content like this (to get the secret key I used `gpg --list-secret-keys`):

```
signing.keyId=xxxxxxx
signing.password=YourPublicKeyPassword
signing.secretKeyRingFile=~/.gnupg/secring.gpg

nexusUsername=YourSonatypeJiraUsername
nexusPassword=YourSonatypeJiraPassword
```

11) `sudo apt-get install gradle` in the terminal because "Andoid Studio" teminal didn't recognize gradle...

12) Finally `gradle uploadArchives`

13) I got this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where: 
Build file '/home/madx/Documents/Workspace/Android-Update-Checker/UpdateCheckerLib/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':UpdateCheckerLib'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'LibraryPlugin'.
```

Probably it is simply due a gradle/gradle plugin problem, but I wanted to share all the procedure, just in case it could be helpful for someone else!

Thanks in advance!

---

### **Publish an aar file to jCenter with Gradle still not working:**

A great thanks goes to JBaruch and his anwer! So I'm trying to publish to jCenter instead of Maven Central, as the matter of fact that jcenter() is a superset of mavenCentral().
Ok let's start again from my github library [Android-Update-Checker](https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/Android-Update-Checker). 
I tried to follow some of his tips but I'm still stuck...
I'm going to write my steps also for the jcenter publishing (hoping that could be useful to someone). Maybe I'm missing something...

1) Registered to Bintray with `username`: danielemaddaluno

2) Enabling the automatically signing of the uploaded content:
from Bintray [profile url](https://bintray.com/profile/edit) --> GPG Signing --> copy paste your `public/private keys`. You can find respectively these two in files `public_key_sender.asc/private_key_sender.asc`
if you execute the following code (the `-a` or `--armor` option in `gpg`is used to generate ASCII-armored key pair):

```
    gpg --gen-key
    gpg -a --export daniele.maddaluno@gmail.com > public_key_sender.asc
    gpg -a --export-secret-key daniele.maddaluno@gmail.com > private_key_sender.asc
```

2.1) In the same [web page](https://bintray.com/profile/edit) you can configure the auto-signing from: Repositories --> Maven --> Check the "GPG Sign uploaded files automatically" --> Update

3) In the same [web page](https://bintray.com/profile/edit) you can find your `Bintray API Key` (copy it for  a later use)

4) In the same [web page](https://bintray.com/profile/edit) you can configure your `Sonatype OSS User` (in the previous section of the question I already created a user and a issue)

5) I added these two lines to the `build.gradle` in the root

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.1"
```

So that my own `build.gradle` in the root looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
        classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

6) I modified my `build.gradle` located inside my project folder, and it looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.bintray"

// This is the library version used when deploying the artifact
version = "1.0.0"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "com.madx.updatechecker.lib"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
}


def siteUrl = 'https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/Android-Update-Checker'      // Homepage URL of the library
def gitUrl = 'https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/Android-Update-Checker.git'   // Git repository URL
group = "com.github.danielemaddaluno.androidupdatechecker"                      // Maven Group ID for the artifact


install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        // This generates POM.xml with proper parameters
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'

                // Add your description here
                name 'The project aims to provide a reusable instrument to check asynchronously if exists any newer released update of your app on the Store.'
                url siteUrl

                // Set your license
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'danielemaddaluno'
                        name 'Daniele Maddaluno'
                        email 'daniele.maddaluno@gmail.com'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection gitUrl
                    developerConnection gitUrl
                    url siteUrl

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}



Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = "maven"
        name = "androidupdatechecker"
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
        publish = true
    }
}
```

7) I added to the root `local.properties` file the following lines:

```
bintray.user=<your bintray username>
bintray.apikey=<your bintray API key>
```

8) Added to my PATH the default gradle 2.2.1 actually used by "Android Studio", for example:

```
PATH=$PATH:/etc/android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.2.1/bin
```

9) Open "Android Studio" terminal and execute:

```
gradle bintrayUpload
```

10) From Bintray --> My Recent Packages --> androidupdatechecker (this is here only after the execution of the previous point 9 ) --> Add to Jcenter --> Check the box --> Group Id = "com.github.danielemaddaluno.androidupdatechecker".

11) Finally I tryed to follow: Bintray --> My Recent Packages --> androidupdatechecker --> Maven Central --> Sync but I got this error in the "Sync Status" bar on the right of the page:

```
Last Synced: Never
Last Sync Status: Validation Failed
Last Sync Errors: 
Missing Signature: 
'/com/github/danielemaddaluno/androidupdatechecker/UpdateCheckerLib/1.0.0/UpdateCheckerLib-1.0.0-javadoc.jar.asc' 
does not exist for 'UpdateCheckerLib-1.0.0-javadoc.jar'. 
Missing Signature: 
'/com/github/danielemaddaluno/androidupdatechecker/UpdateCheckerLib/1.0.0/UpdateCheckerLib-1.0.0.aar.asc' 
does not exist for 'UpdateCheckerLib-1.0.0.aar'. 
Missing Signature: 
'/com/github/danielemaddaluno/androidupdatechecker/UpdateCheckerLib/1.0.0/UpdateCheckerLib-1.0.0-sources.jar.asc' 
does not exist for 'UpdateCheckerLib-1.0.0-sources.jar'. 
Missing Signature: 
'/com/github/danielemaddaluno/androidupdatechecker/UpdateCheckerLib/1.0.0/UpdateCheckerLib-1.0.0.pom.asc' 
does not exist for 'UpdateCheckerLib-1.0.0.pom'. 
Invalid POM: /com/github/danielemaddaluno/androidupdatechecker/UpdateCheckerLib/1.0.0/UpdateCheckerLib-1.0.0.pom: 
Project description missing Dropping existing partial staging repository.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can publish your aar to JCenter instead.

1. It's the [default in Android Studio](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-studio-migration-maven-central-jcenter/).
2. You can [sync to Central from there in much easier way](http://blog.bintray.com/2014/02/11/bintray-as-pain-free-gateway-to-maven-central/).
3. It's [so much easier to publish there](http://blog.blundellapps.com/locally-release-an-android-library-for-jcenter-or-maven-central-inclusion/).
4. You can use [oss.jfrog.org for snapshots](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Snapshots+to+oss.jfrog.org).

Comment: Thank you very much JBaruch, I think that now I'm very close to the goal! I write a second section inside the question where I list how I'm trying to publish my lib... (the section that starts with "Publish an aar file to jCenter with Gradle still not working"). I still got an error (described in point 11 of this section)... Maybe I missed something in those steps? From the error it seems like the automatically signing doesn't work...

Comment: I tried adding for the gradle-bintray-plugin, inside the "pkg" a
`version { gpg { sign = true passphrase = 'bintray.gpg.password' } }`
but command "gradle bintrayUpload" returns me "Could not sign version '1.0.1': HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [message:Failed to sign files for user: 'danielemaddaluno' please make sure that your passphrase is correct.]" (my gpg user when creating the pair of keys was "Daniele Maddaluno <daniele.maddaluno@gmail.com>" could this be a problem?)...

Comment: `'bintray.gpg.password'` is a string that means just that verbatim. If you meant is using a property, you probably wanted `bintray.gpg.password`

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your patience! I forgot to convert it to `properties.getProperty("bintray.gpg.password")`
now signature seems to be fine but i still get an error when syncing with OSS:
`Sync Status
Last Synced: Never
Last Sync Status: Validation Failed
Last Sync Errors: Invalid POM: /com/github/danielemaddaluno/androidupdatechecker/library/1.0.1/library-1.0.1.pom: Project description missing Dropping existing partial staging repository.`
What could be the problem?

Comment: However I rewrite the followed steps clearly for newbie people like me here: https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/gradle-jcenter-publish
(step 16 returns the error described in the previous comment)

Comment: Ok I forgot the description field in the POM generator! Now it returns me "Successfully synced and closed repo"!
Thank you I think I'm done! :D

Comment: Yay! The only thing left is accepting the answer :-)

Comment: Yes I was only waiting too be sure that it is effectively synced with mvn central! Surely I'll accept your answer! Unfortunately I have some other stupid questions related to this...I received 3 mails:
1. Nexus:Staging Completed
2. Nexus:Promotion Completed
3. Nexus:Staging Repository Dropped(inner message: "The comgithubdmadda-1007 staging repository has been dropped.
Action performed by ossrh-cli")
Do you have some useful link (like your answer's ones) from which I could understand what these links are talking about? :)
The third makes me think that something went wrong, but probably not.

Comment: Why now my library compiles with `repositories {mavenCentral()}` specified inside the `dependencies` field but not with `repositories {jcenter()}`? Isn't jcenter a superset of mavencentral, is it? Thank you again!

Comment: What fails? Which dependency can't be found? (It is).

Comment: Re the Nexus stupid emails, you can safely disregard them. The sync status in Bintray is all you need.

Comment: Fantastic! :) I'm loving Bintray!
Regarding to the failure:
With this `dependencies {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.github.danielemaddaluno.androidupdatechecker:library:+'
}` I get an Android Studio "Failed to resolve: com.github.danielemaddaluno.androidupdatechecker:library:+".

Comment: Instead with this `dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.github.danielemaddaluno.androidupdatechecker:library:+'
}` everything goes fine...

Comment: Can you try specific version of the `androidupdatechecker`? Using latest is a horrible idea (although it should work).

Comment: Yeah! It was the plus! Without it works fine!
So with `dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.github.danielemaddaluno.androidupdatechecker:library:1.0.2'
}` it compiles.

Thank you again master! You drove me all along the process of publishing!

Answer (score 7):

Every step I needed to publish my aar file to JCenter and then syncronize it with Maven Central could be read here:
https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/gradle-jcenter-publish

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Isn't there an easier way to upload an artifact to jCentral? It seems to me like it should be rather common operation and should be accomplished by adding just several lines to gradle build file. I believe that the described approach will work (and I'm gonna to follow it) however 17 steps, creating 2 accounts and all that extra customizations in gradle file looks rather overheaded to me.

Comment: I hope it exists, but I don't know other ways. :-) 
However some of these steps must be done only the first time that you upload an artifact. Let me know if you find a simpler way. :-D

Comment: i know this is an old answer, but jcenter is dead